# Как можно использовать Markdown HTML + JS?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

Как можно использовать Markdown HTML + JS?
Не могу понять, нужно устанавливать дополнительную библиотеку для этого языка? Или как это делать?

Comment: Подскажите, для чего вы хотите использовать Markdown?

Comment: @РоманПарадеев Для  сообщений , пишим текстом - получаем html.

Comment: Ну, смотря в каком контексте. Для веб-приложения вам потребуется библиотека. А если локальный предпросмотр, так есть редакторы, в которые он встроен или легко устанавливается. Скажем, в Atom есть встроенный предпросмотр.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам понадобится парсер markdown, чтобы преобразовать его в HTML.

Например, можно воспользоваться библиотекой [markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js).

```js
const message = `
# Список покупок

- молоко
- хлеб
- сыр
`;

const article = document.querySelector('article');
article.innerHTML = markdown.toHTML(message);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown.js/0.5.0/markdown.min.js"></script>
<article></article>
```

Answer (score 4):

Извиняюсь, что подрезал код редактора из примера @Роман Парадеев, но вот простой пример на `jQuery` аля  "пишем текстом - получаем html".

```js
$('.field').on('input propertychange', function() {
  var message = $('.field').val();
  $('article').text(markdown.toHTML(message));
});
```

```css
.field {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown.js/0.5.0/markdown.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="field" rows="7"></textarea>
<article></article>
```

Comment: А как обратно?)